# WSO2 federated authenticator with direct login URL

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have an application that uses both Basic Authentication and a custom OAuth 2.0 Federated Authentication using advanced configuration in identity service. I was wondering is there any way to select federated authenticator and not showing login page to the user? is there any direct login URL that redirect users to the federated authenticator? or is there any other way to achieve this by changing Custom Federated Authenticator?

I used [Custom OAuth 2.0 Federated Authenticator](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/federation/write-a-custom-oauth2-federated-authenticator/) for this purpose and I can only achieve wanted result by setting identity service Authentication Type to Federated Authentication and by this way I lose access to my Basic Authentication option.

Comment: `I was wondering is there any way to select federated authenticator and not showing login page to the user? ` you mean not showing the basic authentication, directly redirecting the user to the federated authenticator? if yes select the configured authenticator as the `federated authentication` in Authentication type.

Comment: Yes but I also need the login page for basic authentication, I simply need two login URL's, one for two option login page(Basic and Federation) and one that directly redirect user to the federated authenticator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your created Identity provider, define a value for "Home Realm Identifer".

[image]

Then access the /oauth2/authorize endpoint with `fidp=<home realm identifier value>` query param.

For example:

```
https://<IS-HOST>:<IS-PORT>/oauth2/authorize?fidp=<home realm identifer of IDP>&scope=<scopes>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<callback url>&client_id=<client id of the application>
```

This will redirect you to the particular federated IDP instead of showing the login page with multi options (basic auth + FIDP).
If you want to get the multi-option login page, don't specify the fidp query param.